# How to implement Specific Row Coloring in PHP?

Tags: php, if-statement, colors, row

I'm trying to colour all the table rows in which the table column `status = O` to **yellow**.  And all the table rows in which the table column `status = P` to **green**.

I'm having trouble editing the current IF statement to get my desired output.  Right now my code looks like this:

```
if ($difflogtime <= $calctimespan || ($rid == 0 && ($status == 'O' ||  $status      == 'P'))){
    echo"<tr valign='top' BGCOLOR='green'>";
    if ($editmode == 1)
        echo "<td valign='top'><Center><font face='Arial' size=2><img src='closedlock.gif' alt='Closed for editing' width='30%'></td>";
    else
        // echo "<td><center><img src='openlock.gif' alt='Open for    editing' border='0' width='30%'></td>";
        echo "<td><center><font  face='Arial' size =   2>$trimref</font></td>";
        echo "<td><Center><font  face='Arial' size =   2>".$dateshow1."</td>";
        echo "<td><Center><font face='Arial' size = 2>".$logtime."</td>";
```

This displays every row in green. Can someone help me alter this code to get the desired output?  That would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you

Please note: This is a php file using a microsoft access database and running some simple sql queries.

Comment: I just noticed that you asked this question 3 times in the last few hours. You should wait for an answer in the first question and not to ask again to get more answers. My solution was already proposed. If you can't make it work than you should go back the basics.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
  $color = ($status=="O")? "YELLOW" : "GREEN"; 
  echo"<tr valign='top' BGCOLOR=\"$color\">";
```

Comment: where should i put that in my code? Inside the first if statement or before it?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have anything in your code that check the status and then determine the color
I would add this :

```
$bgColor = "yellow";
if ($status == 'O'){
    $bgColor = "green";
}
```

and then use the $bgColor parameter:

```
echo '<tr valign="top" BGCOLOR="' . $bgColor . '">";
```

Anyway, You should try to use some CSS. Your style of code is deprecated.
This would be much better:

CSS Code:

```
.yellowStyle{
    vertical-align: top;
    background-color: yellow;
 }

 .greenStyle{
    vertical-align: top;
    background-color: green;
  }
```

Your PHP/HTML:

```
if ($difflogtime <= $calctimespan || ($rid == 0 && ($status == 'O' || $status == 'P')){
    $styleType = "yellowStyle";
    if ($status == 'O'){
        $styleType = "greenStyle";
    }
    echo"<tr class="' . $styleType . '">";
    ....
    ....
 }
```

As you asked, this is your code combined with my solution:

```
if ($difflogtime <= $calctimespan || ($rid == 0 && ($status == 'O' || $status == 'P')){
    $bgColor = "yellow";
    if ($status == 'O'){
        $bgColor = "green";
    }
    echo '<tr valign="top" BGCOLOR="' . $bgColor . '">';
    if ($editmode == 1){
        echo "<td valign='top'><Center><font face='Arial' size=2><img src='closedlock.gif' alt='Closed for editing' width='30%'></td>";
    }
    else{
        // echo "<td><center><img src='openlock.gif' alt='Open for    editing' border='0' width='30%'></td>";
    }
    echo "<td><center><font  face='Arial' size =   2>" . $trimref . "</font></td>";
    echo "<td><Center><font  face='Arial' size =   2>" . $dateshow1 . "</td>";
    echo "<td><Center><font face='Arial' size = 2>" . $logtime . "</td>";
}
```

Note that the `else` "content" is not clear in your code. As you wrote it, it will only include the first echo, that's why I used the indentation that way.

Comment: i tried to input your first method into my code but its giving me errors.  Can you put the code you have suggested into the code given by me?  I'm going to try to run that.

Comment: It gives me this error when I run this: Parse error: parse error, unexpected T_VARIABLE

Comment: I only added the color "if" and changed the first "echo" line. If your code worked before it should work now. If it didn't work before then it's another question and you have to add some more blocks of your code.

Comment: Try to look for missing semicolon or bracket. You presented only part of the code and I can't help if I won't see the rest of the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this ....

```
if ($difflogtime <= $calctimespan || ($rid == 0 && ($status == 'O' ||  $status == 'P'))){
    $color="";
    if ($status=="O"){$color="YELLOW";} else {$color="GREEN";}
    echo "<tr valign='top' BGCOLOR='" . $color . "'>";

    ....
    ....
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$colors = array('O'=>'yellow',
                'P'=>'green');

if ($difflogtime <= $calctimespan || ($rid == 0 && ($status == 'O' ||  $status      == 'P'))){
  echo "<tr valign='top' BGCOLOR='{$colors[$status]}'>";
  .....
```